# What is the correct pom dependency for using jersey webservice?

Tags: java, maven, jersey, pom.xml, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey version 2.12 and I am able to build my project but when I deploy and try to access I get `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`.

When I remove `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar` jar from my webapp/war lib directory I am able to access the rest end points. Please help me with a correct configuration that I can use with Jersey 2.12 and Jersey multipart together.

Below is the full stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [WebAgent] in context with path [/webagent] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:651)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Below is my pom dependency list

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Update** `mvn dependency:tree` command output below

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] com.web:webagent:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11 minutes 39 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 15 17:21:34 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/315M
```

Comment: Run mvn dependeny:tree goal and add the resut at your question?

Comment: @Skizzo: I ran `mvn dependency:tree>tree.txt` but it's a very big file around 1000 lines.. are you looking for any specific info? I updated with dependency part of the result in my question

Comment: Wasn't the answer helpfull and/or do you need something more?

Answer (score 3):

First things first: Don't mix jersey versions!

Example pom, which is use:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jersey.version>2.12</jersey.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- ... -->

</dependencies>
```

Hope this helps, have a nice day.

Comment: It helped me btw. Danke

Answer (score 1):

Try to take the same version in all

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${Jersey version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${Jersey version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${Jersey version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${Jersey version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>${Jersey version}</version>
    </dependency>
```